# Вставка ошибки (какого-либо контента) в определенный блок

Tags: php, jquery

**Суть вопроса:** Есть ошибка, "Вы ввели неправильный логин/пароль", хочу её вставить в определенный блок с помощью **`php`**, если не получиться - на `jq`.

```
php
    
} else {
  print "Вы ввели неправильный логин/пароль";
}
```

Есть вариант делать блок, и изначально его скрыть, потом блок с помощью `jq` переместить в определенный блок и показать, но лично у меня получается - не очень.

Answer (score 0):

В PHP не силён, но можно следующий образом

```
<body>
  <form>
    <inpit type="text" name="login">
    <inpit type="password" name="password">
    <div class="elem">
    <?php 
      if($_GET['login'] !== $login || $_GET['password'] !== $password) {
        echo 'Логин или пароль не совпадают';
      }
    ?>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Но тогда, форма должна обрабатываться этим же файлом `page.php`, что мне кажется, не хорошо..

По этому лучше использовать обработку через AJAX и в случае ошибки через JS\JQ вставлять текст ошибки в нужный элемент.

Comment: Решение довольно интересное. Вопрос про реализацию на `Ajax`, как лучше обрабатывать и делать проверки?

Comment: Со стороны клиента или сервера?

Comment: Со стороны клиента и сервера.

Comment: С клиентской, максимум какие проверки - совпадение по "шаблону" инпута (типо минимальная длина пароля), остальное всё на сервере, там, вроде, ничего не меняется - проверки всё те же, которые [советуют](https://it-black.ru/sozdanie-sistemy-registracii-i-avtorizacii-na-php/).

Comment: Когда у обработчика тот же адрес, что и формы, это наоборот - очень хорошо. Разом снимает кучу проблем

Comment: @Ипатьев, а можно узнать какие?)

Comment: Например, очевидная любому разработчику проблема с тем, чтобы после обработки формы вернуться на исходную страницу